# Fullscreen <div> big as <body>

Tags: css

I want to create a box that goes over the whole width of the screen, so always responsive the full screen width.

My current CSS code always limited the box to the Boddy, but I want the full width.

In addition, I want a background image in the box.

Can someone help me?

My CSS:

```
div.bg {
background-image: url("LINK TO PIC");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Is there something which prevents you from setting the div as `position:fixed`?

If not, it's quite simple:

```
div.bg 
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    background-image: url("LINK TO PIC");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hello Luca

Thanks for your quick Antort.

When I try your code I get a background image on the entire page. I want to but this is a bar across the full width of the background image, the same as a Footer

Comment: So you want it to be stretching over the full width but only over a limited height? Then just set `height` to something different then `100%`, e.g. `height:50px;` ;)

Comment: Hey, very good. The image now has the full width and is 50 px high.

Now the image is always at the top of the site, I would like to have it always at the bottom, above the Footer

Comment: For this you have to work with the absolute positioning, e.g. use `bottom:0` instead of `top:0`. But I think you should start searching for some basic knowledge about CSS, this basic stuff is easily findable on the internet ;)

Comment: div.bg {
    background-image: url("LINK TO PIC");
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

Comment: Hey Luca, it works !!!

I am a complete novice, thank you for your help

Comment: @Luca, update your answer if extra changes were needed in the comments. thanks

Comment: The <div> box works and scrolls always at the bottom.
Now I would like a small X in the right corner so that the user can close the box, best function to close and reopen

Answer (score 0):

Use [Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```
div.bg {
    background-image: url("LINK TO PIC");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;    
}
```

[read more](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

Answer (score 0):

```
div.bg {
background-image: url("LINK TO PIC");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 9;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  box works and scrolls always at the bottom.
Now I would like a small X in the right corner so that the user can close the box, best function to close and reopen